The response time of Geoserver (JVM) makes high depending on the connections count
I use a K8S cluster to scale my Geoserver application, and I have a performance problem with the Geoserver based on JVM. Jemeter is a tool that I use to check response time. I tried different variants to increase my performance. For example, I provided all resources (16 cpu and 16 ram) of Node to the Geoserver pod and changed the setting of the JVM environment. So all paths of request to Geoserver's services and just request to Geoserver application while test running show me that response time makes high depending of user count (connection initializations).
So my question is: What else can I do to improve JVM response time performance and what factors impact it, excluding ram and cpu resources?

You'd be better off with 16 GeoServers on the node

Yet one not. If I set only the 5 users (threads) parameter in Jemeter, I get a normal stable (about 40-45 milliseconds) response time, but if I set about 100 users, the response time is lower and also not stable (in the range from 100 to 2K milliseconds).

there are many guides to production performance for GeoServer, depending on your datastores, data types, file systems and caching settings for the layers. In general more cores and memory doesn't help

Oh, thanks for the idea! Our Docker image includes difficult configurations and uses data_dir inside it. I thought what if I use a clear version of Geoserver from Docker Regestry for the test in our K8s cluster.

But there's one thing that I forgot to tell. I tried to make a request on a simple Geoserver page (not WMS request) and got the same result with response time as a WMS request. Does this behavior also depend on Geoserver internal settings?

no that would depend on your network and machine load
